# How to disable background page scroll when secondary view is open, without changing body css

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, frontend

I'm creating a secondary view that will pop-up on clicking on a link. Content within this secondary view is vertically scrollable and horizontally fixed. The issue is: when scroll reach to the top/bottom of the secondary view, the background page will scroll as well, also if attempt to scroll left/right, the background page will also scroll.

I did some search online but mostly suggest to modify the body css. Due to project constraint, we are not allowed to modify any attribute on body. So I'm trying to find a solution without making css change.

I was trying to achieve using this approach:

```
        secondaryView.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
            if (//mouse scroll up and secondaryView is at top
                || //mouse scroll down and secondaryView is at bottom
                || //mouse scroll left or right) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

However, the problem is I don't know how to detect whether mouse scroll is horizontal, not able to rely on `event.deltaX` since it will be non-zero sometimes when scrolling up or down as well.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a lot of solutions (see [this huge Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) for options), one of which is listening for `scroll` event instead of the `wheel` one (after all, you do not want to be limited to mouse wheel, do you?).

The easiest version (given that for some reason you cannot modify styling) is to keep track of the last known scroll position of the primary view (or the window) and as soon as the secondary view is shown (a boolean flag should suffice), start snapping the primary to it with [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

The rest depends on your exact requirements - if you need the primary to be scrollable *while* the secondary is open, things become complex (a solution for mouse-based devices may be to track cursor position to determine what is scrolled).

```js
(() => {

  const p = document.getElementById("primary");
  const s = document.getElementById("secondary");
  const b = document.getElementById("show");

  let secondaryShown = false;

  b.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (secondaryShown) {
      s.classList.remove("shown");
      secondaryShown = false;
      return;
    }

    s.classList.add("shown");
    secondaryShown = true;
  });

  let lknownYPos = window.scrollY,
    lknownXPos = window.scrollX;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", ({
    target,
    currentTarget
  }) => {

    if (secondaryShown) {
      window.scrollTo(lknownXPos, lknownYPos)
    }

    lknownWindowPos = window.scrollY;
  }, true);

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.subcontent {
  height: 300vh;
  width: 300vw;
}

#primary {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vh;
}

#secondary {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.shown {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

<div id="primary">

  <button id="show">Switch secondary</button>

  <div id="secondary">
    <p>Secondary</p>
    <div class="subcontent"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```